# Undo accepting the answer

Tags: support, reputation, answers, accepted-answer

When I accept someone's answer to my questio, then this user gets +15 reputation while I get +2 reputation. What will happen if I undo my decision? And what if I further acept somebody's else answer? I'm asking here while I don't want to make experiments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a comprehensive description of actions which lead to reputation change, and by how much: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269653/why-did-i-gain-lose-reputation-can-i-audit-my-reputation-history

So: when you unaccept an answer, you get -2 and the answerer gets -15. In other words, you reverse what happened when you accepted. Same deal if you then accept someone else's: you get +2 and that answerer gets +15.

Comment: I just had an "interesting" experience - my answer was unaccepted, and the poster accepted his own answer, a relatively minor variation of my answer. :-/ I feel it's borderline behaviour, especially as I recalled how poster nagged me for details...